# How to configure volume path in docker-compose with docker swarm

Tags: docker-compose, docker-swarm

I configure docker compose to create default volume but now i need to customize local path of volume, I try to do some driver_opts with binding and specifying path by device options but in that case swarm throw error in container 'Failed to mount ... directory does not exist'. So how I can configure local path of volume ?

This is my docker compose

```
version: '3'

services:
    xxx:
       image: image-xxx
       deploy:
           mode: replicated
           replicas: 2
       volumes:
         - xxxvolume:/usr/src/xxx/yyy/

volumes:
  xxxvolume:
    driver: 'local'
```

And the volume information is

```
[
    {
        "CreatedAt": "2019-11-24T19:05:03+01:00",
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.stack.namespace": "XX"
        },
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/xxx/_data",
        "Name": "XX_xxvolume",
        "Options": null,
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

Comment: Can you try this for volume; "volumes:-./xxxvolume:/usr/src/xxx/yyy/". Only add "./"  at the beginning of the command

Comment: I tried to do it but in that case docker can't even be builded in compose :/

Comment: I've added sample usage. Please review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  jira:
    image: atlassian/jira-software
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/jira_vol:/var/atlassian/application-data/jira
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

volumes:
  jira_vol:
    external: false
```

And run this command;

```
docker-compose up -d
```

Finally volume directory added in same path!

Comment: It work but version 3.7 is required. I had version 3.0 and it does not work. Anyway thanks for help Ali :)